# How to create launch or desktop icon for Matlab 2015a

Tags: unity, software-installation, icons, matlab

I have installed Matlab 2015a on my Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Matlab 2015a on the default path it offered me. which is

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a
```

to run matlab I need to go to the following folder and and go to `/bin` then type `./matlab`. Only then, the matlab runs. Can anyone please help and guide me how to create an icon on launch pad or create a desktop shortcut icon? I really need help.

Comment: Have a long at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Dear Ron, Thank you for your support. I have been able to solve this problem with the combination of the web page that you suggested as well as others. I would leave a a detailed sample of the instruction and code that used so that, if there are other Matlab R2015a users; and after they install it, they can take help from this question/answer thread.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, since I was new to ubuntu it took me a while to figure out how to solve the above stated problem. I did the following steps as I have arranged it here, below. This should be mentioned here that the directory in which I installed was `/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a`.

1. Download a `*.png` image of the matlab logo using the browser. By default it should be saved in the folder `/home/<username>/Downloads`.
2. Now copy this `*.png` image to the matlab installation directory. I faced trouble using only the `cp` command. Then I used the `sudo cp` command. It was like this `sudo cp /home/<username>/Downloads /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a`. Then it worked.
3. Open an editor like Gedit. Type the following code/text, line by line:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry] 
   Version=1.0 
   Name=Matlab 2015a  
   Comment=Launch Matlab
   2015a with one click
   Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/matlab
   Icon=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/matlab.png
   Terminal=true 
   Type=Application 
   Catagories=Utility;Application;
   ```

   Now save the file with the name `Matlab 2015a.desktop`. After this, you should see a normal file on your desktop. right click on the file and go to *Properties*. click on *Permission* then click on *Allow executing file as program*. This time the file you created on your desktop should have the Matlab logo.
4. Double click on the Matlab 2015a logo that you created and enjoy your hard work.

Comment: Why `chmod 777`? The Matlab directory already needs to have read and traversal permissions for everybody so everybody can run it and so will any file copied there with `sudo cp`. Don't go around and make files and directories world-writeable for no reason! I removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to create shortcuts for any Applications.

what you have to do is just download a .png file that you want to set as "icon"

and find the path from where you are executing(opening) it from terminal

In my case my my png file is in `/usr/share/icons/matlab.png`
and executable "matlab" file is at /`usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/`

now open any text editor "gedit" and paste below commands and replace  respective paths and save the file with `name.desktop` where `name` is anything you want.

[Note: To create launcher on DOC I will recommend you to save `name.desktop` on `Desktop` folder.]

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Matlab R2015a
Comment=MATLAB shortcut!
Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Production_Server/R2015a/bin/matlab
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

now right click on file goto--->`properties-->permissions` and at bottom select `Allow executing file as program`
Hurray you did it.
Now just double click and enjoy the shortcut.